# Hooking up React Redux to a Component in Typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am looking to hook up React Redux to my component in typescript. I am using these [docs](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/static-typing) as a template.

I have the following type defining the state I have in the Redux store (there is only one):

```
export interface rootState {
  favourites: ImageThumbnail[]
}
```

My component:

```
...

interface StateProps {
  favourites: NasaImageThumbnail[]
}

interface DispatchProps {
  addFavourite: () => void
  removeFavourite: () => void
}

interface OwnProps {
  ...
}

const mapState = (state: rootState) => ({
  favourites: state.favourites
})

const mapDispatch = {
  addFavourite: () => ({ type: 'ADD_FAVOURITE' }),
  removeFavourite: () => ({ type: 'REMOVE_FAVOURITE' })
}

type combinedProps = StateProps & DispatchProps & OwnProps

//Component body

export default connect<StateProps, DispatchProps, OwnProps>(
  mapState,
  mapDispatch
)(Component)
```

mapState within the connect function is producing the following error:

> No overload matches this call.   The last overload gave the following
> error.
> Argument of type '(state: rootState) => { favourites: ImageThumbnail[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'MapStateToPropsParam<StateProps, OwnProps, DefaultRootState>'.
> Type '(state: rootState) => { favourites: ImageThumbnail[]; }' is not assignable to type 'MapStateToPropsFactory<StateProps,
> OwnProps, DefaultRootState>'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't pass all those generic args to `connect`.  They should generally be inferred.

In fact, per that page, [we specifically recommend using the `ConnectedProps<T>` technique to infer the type of props passed from `connect` to your component](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/static-typing#inferring-the-connected-props-automatically).

You should also note that:

- We recommend using [our official Redux Toolkit package for writing your Redux logic](https://redux-toolkit.js.org)
- As part of that, [you should infer the `RootState` type from your root reducer or store](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#getting-the-state-type)
- We recommend [using the React-Redux hooks API as the default instead of `connect`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks), and one of the reasons is that it's easier to use with TypeScript

Comment: Curios about the recommendation to prefer redux hooks. I'm new to React-Redux but am developing a large project using redux-toolkit. My biggest concern with hooks is that the component has knowledge about the root state shape and I can't reuse it or refactor my code without changing the selector in every component. Currently, I am connecting my components in my slice file after I create the state slice so if I do change the state all of my required connection updates are in one place. My hooks concerns are reusability and coupling of components to state shape. Maybe my concern is misguided?

Comment: The question is understandable, but not a serious concern. The "selector state shape" question applies regardless of whether you're using `connect + mapState` or `useSelector`, because _both_ of them receive the root Redux state object as their only argument. No difference there. If you are strongly concerned with avoiding rewriting anonymous selectors in components, create a reusable selector that can be called in many components instead so that you only have to edit the reducer and that selector if the state shape ever changes.

Comment: For more details on this, see my posts [Using Reselect Selectors for Encapsulation and Performance](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/12/idiomatic-redux-using-reselect-selectors/), [Thoughts on React Hooks, Redux, and Separation of Concerns](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2019/07/blogged-answers-thoughts-on-hooks/),  and [ReactBoston 2019: Hooks, HOCs, and Tradeoffs](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2019/09/presentation-hooks-hocs-tradeoffs/). This is also a good argument for using TypeScript as well.

Comment: Oh, and I would avoid defining component connections in the slice file. Definitely not an idiomatic approach, and tbh I can't remember ever seeing anyone else ever do that.

Comment: The connection in the slice file was something I did because I didn't want to import other parts of my project into my component (except for interfaces which I keep in another file per feature). My reasoning was that if I'm defining my state slice in one file, the connected components are associated with the state so why should I do the connection in the component file? Seeing the connect at the bottom of the component file never felt great to me even though I did see examples of that. I'm a complete noob to redux-react and thanks for Redux-Toolkit.

Comment: I'll look into re-usable selectors thanks , still trying to wrap my head around how re-rendering works with useSelector. My current impression is that with HOC the render function doesn't get called at all if there is no "change" in passed component props. With useSelector it seems the rendering function has to get called for useSelector to be called and then React sees the returned object is the same so it doesn't re-render it. I haven't looked into this to actually verify that's just my impression from reading about them.

Comment: Yeah, connecting at the bottom of a component file has always been the standard approach. `useSelector` works equivalent to `connect+mapState`, just with one value at a time instead of an object of them - they both internally subscribe to the Redux store and re-check values after any action was dispatched. See my post [The History and Implementation of React-Redux](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/11/react-redux-history-implementation/) and talk [ReactNext 2019: A Deep Dive into React-Redux](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2019/06/presentation-react-redux-deep-dive/).